# How to recognize alternative expression using natural language processing

Tags: nlp, opennlp

I'm trying to use opennlp to understand alternative expression of user query. For example, "Kate Winslet movie" and "movie by Kate Winslet" are of the same meaning. I want opennlp to generate the same machine query for the two user inputs. What is the best approach to the different expressions of same meaning?

Thanks